# Update object with new relationships before post changes

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a model named "Professional" that have as attribute a list of other objects named "Skill".

At my edit page I'm trying to do something that will list all skills persisted at database and the user will choice someone and create a link with that skill.

But I have no idea how can i achieve this:

My Edit View:

```
@model TCCApplication.Models.ProfessionalModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ProfessionalModel</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserAccount.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserAddress.Id)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Profession)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Profession)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Profession)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserAccount.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserAccount.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserAccount.Username)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserAccount.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserAccount.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserAccount.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserAddress.Street)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserAddress.Street)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserAddress.Street)
        </div>

        <fieldset class="row">
            <legend>Habilidades</legend>

            @foreach (var skill in Model.Skills)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(sk => skill.Id)

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="display-label">
                        @Html.Label("Nome da habilidade: ")

                        @Html.DisplayFor(sk => skill.Name)
                    </div>

                    <div class="display-label">
                        @Html.Label("Descrição")

                        @Html.DisplayFor(sk => skill.Description)
                    </div>

                    <div class="display-label">
                        @Html.Label("Categoria: ")

                        @Html.DisplayFor(sk => skill.Category.Name)
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Deletar Skill", "DeleteSkill", new { skillId = skill.Id, professionalId = Model.Id })
                </div>
            }

            <p>

                <div>
                    @Html.DropDownList("Skills", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.skills)
                </div>

            </p>


            <div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Adicionar habilidade não presente na lista", "AddNewSkill", new { professionalId = Model.Id})
            </div>

        </fieldset>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get a list of distinct strings from the database.

Controller:

`ViewBag.Skills = db.Skills.OrderBy(c=>c.Name).Select(c => c.Name).Distinct().ToList();`

This will put the strings gathered previously into a multi-select list.

View:

`@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Skills, ((List<int>)ViewBag.Skills).Select(m=> new SelectListItem{Value = m.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Text = m.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}), new {multiple = "multiple"})`

You can approach this a bit more intelligently by creating a list of SelectListItems from the result of your db result by putting the value to the ID and the text to the name. That'll make it easier to save changes later.